# Bandwidth to hosts abroad

Tags: bandwidth, network-speed

I have a server with 1 Gbps uplink. Testing gives me a download/upload speed of approx 600 Mbps to servers nearby in Europe, and 100 Mbps to servers in US.

I want to host a server and I need to know if I will have enough bandwidth.

If I upload to multiple hosts in the US, will the total speed be limited at 100 Mbps? (the same speed I get when trying to Download/Upload to 1 server in the US).

Comment: most likely. The bandwidth is likely limited by capacity rather than an indication of number of hosts. How did you measure bandwidth? Do you think this is similar to the behaviour of a multiple hosts traffic?

Answer (score 1):

The further from you the server you're testing against, the higher the latency. Higher latency reduces throughput with TCP connections due to how the protocol works. The speeds you've posted look fine.

If you run multiple speed tests in parallel you'll likely get closer to 1Gbps, but probably not quite reach it due to TCP overheads.

Have a read of [this](https://www.performancevision.com/blog/measuring-network-performance-latency-throughput-packet-loss/), and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/870177/can-excessive-latency-affect-throughput).

Whether it's fast enough depends on what you're hosting. If you're serving streaming video to 10,000 people at the same time, probably not. If you're running 50 wordpress sites with moderate traffic, probably fine.